# Check if value is within range otherwise calculate nearest value

Tags: swift, math, random, numbers

I have these value:

```
let previous = 170
let min = 100
let max = 800
```

So what I´m doing is that I´m generating a random number between `min` and `max`, with these rules:

- `min` not less than 100
- `max` not more than 800
- I only want to have +200 from `previous` or -200 from `previous`

So for the above example the random number should be between:
**min: 100 and max 370.**

`Min` is 100 because min can´t be less than 100 and `max` is basically previous: 170 + 200.

I tried the `"pattern-match" operator ~=:` but it did not feel like the right component to do here.

Any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can "clamp" (or "limit") a range to another range:

```
let previous = 170
let min = 100
let max = 800

let range = (previous-200...previous+200).clamped(to: min...max)
print(range.lowerBound, range.upperBound) // 100 370
```

Now compute the random number in the reduced range:

```
let r = range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.count)))
```

See [`clamped(to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countableclosedrange/1782385-clamped) for the details. In particular,
if the ranges don't overlap then  the result is the
single-element range in the given limit which is closest to the receiver:

```
let previous = 2000
let min = 100
let max = 800

let range = (previous-200...previous+200).clamped(to: min...max)
print(range.lowerBound, range.upperBound) // 800 800
```